# When we have some constants defined in a class in Ruby and Rails, can we guarantee to be able to access it in another class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If we have some constants inside of a class definition:

```
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
  GROWTH_FACTOR = 2

  ...
end
```

is it true that sometimes `Animal::GROWTH_FACTOR` is available to be used by another class or ERB, such as

```
class Plant < ActiveRecord::Base
  GROWTH_FACTOR = Animal::GROWTH_FACTOR / 2.0

  ...
end
```

or

```
<%= Animal::GROWTH_FACTOR %>
```

but sometimes not? (so it would be randomly failing, depending whether the Rails server re-run the class definition of `Animal` for that particular HTTP request?) Is `GROWTH_FACTOR` only really guaranteed to be useable inside of each class's own definition?  What if we want to guarantee it is available, is it to use `@@GROWTH_FACTOR` inside the class and then use `Animal.GROWTH_FACTOR` every where else in the code?

Comment: Is there one and only one definition of `Animal`? Don't use class variables, and *especially* don't use all-caps ones masquerading as constants. That's not how they work.

Comment: Why not define a `GrowthFactor` concern where you can organize all of these, and then use those values in other places?

Comment: @tadman what if you know these constants never change? Such as if it is `Phone` and `SCREEN_SIZE = { iPhone5 : { width: 1080, height: 1920 } , ... }`, which is supposed to never change?

Answer (score 1):

In your example, 'Animal' and 'Plant' are both global constants. As long as these declarations have been evaluated and as long as they haven't been somehow undefined, they're both accessible from anywhere, including any constants defined inside the classes.

If these two classes are defined in files named 'animal.rb' and 'plant.rb', then you can be sure both constants are available by `require`ing these files. If one depends on the other, then the order you require the files in matters.

Now in the second part of your question you mention a different syntax `@@` which is not the same thing. I'd steer clear of that syntax unless you fully understand what a class variable is all about in Ruby.

Comment: so you mean if I want a constant for a class which is `Animal::GROWTH_FACTOR`, then this method or `Animal.GROWTH_FACTOR` and `@@GROWTH_FACTOR` work equally well?  And they really are not constants but both can refer to another object, can't they?

Comment: I actually don't see any `require` and it seems sometimes it works and sometimes not... by the way, if you need a `require` but you don't have it, shouldn't the behavior be that it always error and won't run?

Comment: You can store value in Ruby class variable, but I would avoid them unless you're absolutely sure you need them. The fairly-well-accepted Ruby style guide recommends this: https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#no-class-vars

You may be falling victim to behavior that comes from Reloading (see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html). Try setting `config.cache_classes = true` in config/development.rb to see if that's the case.

The code in your question looks fine, though. Rails *should* autoload Animal for you.

Comment: Our project is using Rails 3.x, so there is no "auto load" mode (zeitwerk)... but that's weird, we don't have `require "Animal"` or `require "Plant"` but the code doesn't error out?  Or maybe it does but is caught by exception handler?  It is strange that in my ERB when I spit out the constants to pass to the JS side, sometimes the static HTML doesn't have that constants section... is it because it is not auto-loaded and actually caused an exception? Does that mean the controller should `require "..."` it before rendering the view/partial?

Comment: The first link you added in last comment is about class variable, but what about `Animal::GROWTH_FACTOR`?  That is not a class variable but a constant as part of the class?

Comment: In this linkhttps://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants_classic_mode.html it actually does the `require`... so does that mean in Rails 3.x, `require` is needed?  What if it is not there, does it always error out, or is by random (whether it got cleared from memory?) I would much rather it always error out instead of randomly, but in our project, I spit out the constants in ERB and those constants are sometimes missing in the main HTML file being generated

Comment: Even Rails 3 has autoloading/reloading features, just not using Zeitwerk (see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/configuring.html). If you use this system, you do not need to specifically 'require' anything, but you do need to follow certain conventions (one class per file, file name must match class name). Please do try toggling the `cache_classes` variable that I mentioned. That will confirm this is a reloading problem.

Comment: in dev, `cache_classes` is `false` by default... so you mean for some reason my setting is that `cache_classes` is `true`, and I might be changing my Rails code and it didn't get noticed by the running Rails server, and as a result, I might be defining `Animal::GROWTH_FACTOR` but the Rails server is not aware of it?